# How to use Front Camera for Barcode Scanning in Firebase ML KIT

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have a case where i need to use ML Kit from firebase for barcode scanning. By default it is using back camera. How can i change it to front facing camera ? I have searched in google firebase ML KIT documentation and couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Could you share some code for how you are starting the camera?

Comment: @Quinn I am using the sample app from Google repo

https://github.com/firebase/mlkit-material-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/ml/md/java/LiveBarcodeScanningActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the mlkit example project you linked is using deprecated camera code, but if you look at the [CameraSource](https://github.com/firebase/mlkit-material-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/ml/md/kotlin/camera/CameraSource.kt) class on line 175 there is the `createCamera` method. Try replacing the following line:

```
val camera = Camera.open() ?: throw IOException("There is no back-facing camera.")
```

with

```
val camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) ?: throw IOException("There is no front-facing camera.")
```